# Mathematica to swf / fla

Tags: export, interactive

Is it possible to export an interactive (in terms of mouse clicks) *Mathematica* manipulation / animation as an interactive swf file, including converted actionscript? I realise this is probably not possible from inside *Mathematica*, but just wondering if there was a 3rd part program that did it?

Comment: No. You have to use CDF for interactive. (you can export to swf ofcourse, but only as a movie, not interactive).

Comment: OK, many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [CDF](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/) to generate interactive documents/applications from Mathematica. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_Document_Format for more information on CDF.

You can export the document and dynamic content (Manipulate, Dynamics) to movie and animated gif files, but these can only be played back, and no interaction is possible with the movie as it plays.

There are no third party tools (that I know about) to author CDF other by using WRI product. You need a CDF player (or plugin) to play the CDF (or if you have Mathematica itself, you can use that ofcourse)

But as always, for an official answer, it is best to contact WRI sales support. I only answer based on what I hear in the news and read on the net.